# Change marker in Google maps on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I'am developing an application that add markers to a map. But use the default marker is some heavy and show unclear information. I'd like to add just small points with a number. How can I do this? O found some tutorials to add image in the placer of the default icon of the marker, but I don't thinks that is the case here.

This is the code i'm using now.

```
                    Marker marked = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(ltlt)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                                    .title("Numero:" + i)
                                    .snippet("Snippet")
                    );
```

My code do this:

[image: My code do this]

I need to do this:

[image: I need to do this]

Comment: Off the cuff, you would need to create a `Bitmap` that has your dot and number, then use `fromBitmap()` on `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

Comment: So.. I basically need something like a yellowDot.png + number1.png + number2.png + number3.png and when i mark put all toghether?

Comment: That, or perhaps use a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas` to draw the text and dot. That is more complicated to program, but it would reduce the number of images you need by a lot.

Comment: i've never seen this bitmap-backed Canvas.. I will look into it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! I found a way to solve it. Post below. Thanks for help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work to me:

Configure the iconGenerator

```
    IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
    iconFactory.setContentPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    iconFactory.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("R.drawable.nada.jpg"));  // transparent image 10px x 10px
    iconFactory.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
```

Style used:

```
<style name="iconGenText">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

and my markeradd:

```
                    Marker marked = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(ltlt)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("" + i)))
                            .title("Numero:" + i)
                            .snippet("Snippet")
                    );
```